# Limit of c^n (with ¦c¦<1) is 0 (Isabelle)

Tags: isabelle, isar

Does anyone know a rule for showing

```
"¦c¦<1 ==> (λn. c^n) ---> 0"
```

in the reals?

I have found the following rules using the 'query' panel:

```
Limits.LIMSEQ_rabs_realpow_zero2: ¦?c¦ < 1 ⟹ op ^ ?c ---> 0
Limits.LIMSEQ_rabs_realpow_zero: ¦?c¦ < 1 ⟹ op ^ ¦?c¦ ---> 0
Limits.LIMSEQ_realpow_zero: 0 ≤ ?x ⟹ ?x < 1 ⟹ op ^ ?x ---> 0
```

although I am a little confused by what `op` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lemma you are trying to prove is precisely `LIMSEQ_rabs_realpow_zero2`. You can therefore prove your goal with `apply (rule LIMSEQ_rabs_realpow_zero2)`.

E.g. try `term "λx y. x + y"` or `term "λx. 1 + x"` in Isabelle. The output will be `op +` and `op + 1`, respectively.

The `op ^` is simply a shorthand for `λx y. x ^ y`. In general, `op` in Isabelle is syntax for turning a binary infix operator into a function with two arguments (a bit like in ML).